# Can I change the centos.iso for replacing the CentOS-Base.repo file?

Tags: centos, repository, iso

When we use centos iso image create a CentOS OS, in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`, there is a default `CentOS-Base.repo`.

and I can replace the `CentOS-Base.repo` to my custom repo file now.

I have a requirement, that is can I change the `CentoS-Base.repo` content in the iso? then I don't need to replace the `CentOS-Base.repo` after install the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create your custom centos.iso but what you need is to install centos with your custom kickstart configuration file.

A **Kickstart Installation** is the way to automate and customize your centos installation and do whatever you like from the same initial centos.iso.

You only need a webserver to server your ks files.

To give you a very simple example here is a basic CentOS7 kickstart file

**CentOS7-ks.cfg**

```bsh
# ebal, Sat, 07 Apr 2018 18:28:19 +0300

#version=CentOS-7

# Install OS instead of upgrade
install

# Text or Graphical mode ?
text

# Packages are on:
cdrom

# System keyboard
keyboard us

# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# TimeZone with NTP
timezone Eurpe/Athens --ntpservers=gr.pool.ntp.org

# SELinux - By default, selinux is enforcing
selinux --permissive

# Sets the system's root password to the password argument.
rootpw --plaintext password

# accept the End User License Agreement - rhel 7
## eula--agreed

# Do not Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --disabled

# Power Off the system when the install is complete
## poweroff
# Reboot the system when the install is complete
reboot


# Partition Table
autopart --nohome --type=plain --fstype=ext4

bootloader --location=mbr

# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
zerombr

%packages --excludedocs
@core
# Remove
-aic94xx-firmware
-alsa-*
-iwl*-firmware
-ivtv-firmware
-libertas-*-firmware
-btrfs-progs
-ModemManager-glib
-NetworkManager*
-wpa_supplicant
# Install
openssh-clients
%end

# Disable Kdump
%addon com_redhat_kdump --disable
```

Then when you start your centos installation from the centos.iso you need to type something like this by hitting tab:

```
inst.ks=http://10.10.10.11/mnt/CentOS7-ks.cfg
```

if you do not want to install a web server, for personal use, you can temporarily use python in the same directory as your CentOS7-ks.cfg file

```
python3 -m http.server
```